# How to Scroll and Pan (left right) in UICollectionView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a simple UICollectionView with the cells in a grid. Each is populated with a name from an array. I'm quite new to programming so i expect i have many things wrong, but that's how we learn.

I've been searching for a method to add a pan gesture but also keep the scrolling activated. Some research mentioned i should cancel the vertical UIPanGestureRecognizer so the scroll knows it should be in control, but i failed to implement this.

The final objective is when you pan either left or right, a judgement function will be called to add points to the side you panned.

I've uploaded a link to the sample project.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5ujdhsssq289ms7/AABovvbIF4npzR7cB9lIOO2Ha?dl=0

My code for the ViewController is:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var name = [String]()
var originalCenter: CGPoint!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.frame)
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width + (width / 3))

    name = ["DAN", "DANIELA", "MIRABELA", "ANGELA", "CARTOCEA", "FANDOSAN"]

}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return name.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    originalCenter = cell.center
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: cell)

    let names = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    names.text = name[indexPath.row]

    let panLeftRight: UIGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    panLeftRight.delegate = self
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(panLeftRight)

    return cell
}

func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    let location = sender.locationInView(self.view)

    var widthForPan = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.frame)

    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(), inView: self.view)

    switch sender.state {

    case .Began:
        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x, y:view.center.y)
        }
    case .Changed:
        if let view = sender.view {

            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                y:view.center.y)
        }
    case .Ended:
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
            if let revine = sender.view {
                revine.center = CGPoint(x: translation.x + widthForPan / 2, y: revine.center.y)
            }
            print(self.originalCenter)
            print(widthForPan)
        }

    default:
        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x,
                y:view.center.y)

        }
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer is what you're looking for. 
More info can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

What is happening is that the first recognizer "claims" the touch for himself. The other recognizer does not get a touch event, and thus does nothing.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans worked perfectly, thank you! It's weird, i've implemented this before and it didn't work, must have done something wrong.

    'func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }'

This is the code, if anyone is looking for it.